# I would like to modify header for all xhr requests

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I would like to modify my HeaderResponse after login function. Actually i can modify/add new section in response fields with this

> HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Example", "example");

But it doesnt effect all requests. it effects only one requests.

```
[HttpPost]
        [Route("Account/Login")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]

        public JsonResult Login(string username, string password)
        {
            AccountModel am = new AccountModel(username, password);
            am.Find(username);
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(username) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(password) ||
                am.Login(username, password) == null)
            {

                var data = new { status = "false", message = "Account is Invalid" };

                return Json(data,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }

          ////////HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Example", "example");

            return Json(....,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Basicly, I would like to create HeaderResponse after login progress. I think, i need kind of HttpGlobalContext.Response or something like that. Is it possible to do that? Or is there any alternative way for it.

Comment: are you using owin?

Comment: yes, im using owin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve what you are trying to achieve.

1.Adding an OWIN Middleware

```
public override async Task Invoke(IOwinContext context) {
    //call Headers.Add() method
    context.Response.Headers.Add("key",value);
    await Next.Invoke(context); }
```

2.Adding a base controller override the `OnActionExecuting` to add the header value